# transform xml to java in android (dynamic UI)

Tags: java, android

hi to everyone i have this code in xml and i want transform this to java

```
<TableRow>
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnImg1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:src="@drawable/one"/>
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnImg2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:src="@drawable/two"/>
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnImg13"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:src="@drawable/three"/>

</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnImg4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/four"/>
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnImg5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/five"/>
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnImg6"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/six"/>

</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnImg7"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/seven"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnImg8"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/eight"
        android:onClick="onClick2"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnImg9"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/nine"
        android:onClick="onClick3"/>


</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnImg10"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/seven"/>
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnImg11"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/eight"/>
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnImg12"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/nine"/>

</TableRow>
```

i write this in java but when i run all the imagebutton are duplicate on together:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setContentView(R.layout.main);
    LayoutParams params =
            new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    TableRow table = new TableRow(this);
    table.setOrientation(TableRow.VERTICAL);

    ImageButton ib = new ImageButton(this);
    ib.setImageResource(R.drawable.one);
    ib.setLayoutParams(params);
    ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v){

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"button clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
    });

    ImageButton ib2 = new ImageButton(this);
    ib.setImageResource(R.drawable.two);
    ib.setLayoutParams(params);
    ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v){
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"button clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
    });

    table.addView(ib);
    table.addView(ib2);

    TableRow.LayoutParams layoutParams=
            new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT );
    this.addContentView(table, layoutParams);

}
```

this is just for 2 imagebutton but this hapend too...thank you

Comment: Could you give a quick explanation as to why you want this in java code?

Its all defined in your XML (except for the onclick). And I see you're using resources anyway (R.drawable) so why do you want to put this in java?

Android automatically transforms XML into java code for you.

Comment: I think you're confused, You basically want to you them, right? You don't have to make them dynamically to use them, just inflate the xml and use them.

Comment: i want have dynamic image button in other situation get another image and i can programing this in java(dynamic UI)

Comment: i need dynamic in future.